# 404 Not Found when deploying Flask on WSGI

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, flask, mod-wsgi

I've been using Flask for a while for development but recently decided to address the "This server should not be used for production" warning. I've spent several hours trying to get wsgi to work to no avail.

Here's the structure of my /var/www:

```
webApp
   webApp
      static
      templates
      __init__.py
   webapp.wsgi
```

My webapp.wsgi file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/webApp/")

from webApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

My webApp.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my_vps_ip
    ServerAdmin email@mywebsite.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/webApp/webapp.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/webApp/webApp/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/webApp/webApp/static
    <Directory /var/www/webApp/webApp/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And finally, my `__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def test():
    return 'test'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And this happens when I visit the server ip:

[image]

Why could this be happening? I've spent all day trying to figure this out, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can You please check the serverName is correct and should be a registered domain.